# Make centered container div fit on mobile?

Tags: css, media-queries

The centered div in question:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 550px;
  width: auto;
  background: rgba(28, 28, 54, 0.70);
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1d29;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
}

#actualcontainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 550px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c36;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: clip;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  overflow-y: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#sidebar p {
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar img {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sideimage {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url('/img.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 175%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#description {
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 135px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -10px 0;
}

#linkcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#links {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f7e5a3;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(28, 28, 54, 0.70);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 3px 3px 1.5px 3px;
  line-height: 200%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="actualcontainer">


    <div id="content">

      <!-- start content -->

      <h1>Text text text</h1>

      <p align="center">Text text text</p>

      <!-- end content -->

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">

      <div class="sideimage"></div>
      <div id="title">Text text text</div>

      <div id="description">
        <p>Text text text Text text text Text text text</p>
      </div>

      <div id="linkcontainer">
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
        <div id="links"><a href="/link"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><br>link</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**What is happening now:**

- **On desktop:** this centers as desired, with no edges clipping or overflowing the window's edge.
- **On mobile (portrait mode):** also centers as desired, and everything shrinks / scales to fit the screen's boundaries.
- **On mobile (landscape mode):** the container is suddenly too big to fit the screen, and the very top and bottom are cut off.

**What I want to happen:** *For mobile landscape mode to be subject to the same type of scaling as portrait mode*, where there is visible space between the container and the screen edges and nothing is cut off.

**What I've already tried:**

- **Simply making everything smaller** via CSS (the above code is the result, and things are still cut off)
- **Implementing media query** and using `transform:scale(0.75);`

  - Using `@media (max-width: 600px)` and applying the scale to `#container`: Nothing happens.
  - Using `@media (max-height: 600px)` and applying the scale to `#container`: The container does get smaller, but it is shoved to the bottom right, and you have to scroll to get to it.
  - Using `@media (max-width: 600px)` and applying the scale to `body`: The container does get smaller, but it is shoved to the top of the screen and now half of it is cut off, and I can't scroll to get to the rest.
  - Using `@media (max-height: 600px)` and applying the scale to `body`: Same as above.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Comment: @Rob added full css + html. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using scale in the media query, try using the 100vh and 100vw values in CSS. 100vw means 100% of the viewport's width (the user's screen), and 100vh mean 100% of the viewport's height.

So if you use this CSS feature and add padding using the calc() function (for some nice padding) you can make the container resize based on the screen size.

A way this solution could be implemented is this:

```
#container{
    max-width: calc(100vw - 20px);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

This ensures the container always fits inside the screen. Make sure to enable scroll on overflow or you're going to have issues. Also keep in mind all this is **terrible practice** and as you get better, you should learn to not do this.

I hope I could answer your question, feel free to ask if you have any more issues. Happy coding!

Comment: Technically works, but when I go to add stuff into the container it gets knocked out of alignment. Whatever solution there is needs to affect both the container and everything in it.

Comment: try adding overflow:scroll; to the containter to fix it